# C# async await: How do i write an async method for my example shown below?

Tags: c#, async-await

Here is the code snippet and I get a warning:

> this async method lacks await operators and will run synchronously. Consider using the await operator to await non-blocking calls.

```cs
    public async Task<ActionResult> CreateRequest([FromBody] DnsRecordDto RecordRequested)
    {
        var result = IsRecordRequestedNull()
    }

    public bool IsRecordRequestedNull(DnsRecordDto RecordRequested)
    {
        bool flag = false;
        if (RecordRequested == null)
        {
            flag = true;
            _commonRepository.SaveLogItem(Constants.TransactionFailedBadData, Constants.STARTING, transId, LogLevel.Trace);
        }
        return flag;
    }
```

I am not sure how to address this warning

Do i really need to decorate the IsRecordRequestedNull with an async keyword and make it run async just because i am calling this method from an async method?

In such cases should i ignore the warning that appears..?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using the [`async`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/async) keyword does not, by itself, make a method run asynchronously. It just enables the use of the [`await`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/await) operator. If you aren't using `await`, don't use `async`.

The warning is just saying: "You're not using `await`, so why are you using `async`?"

If you aren't using or can't use `await`, then the fix is just to remove the `async` keyword:

```
public ActionResult CreateRequest([FromBody] DnsRecordDto RecordRequested)
{
    var result = IsRecordRequestedNull()
}
```

If there is an asynchronous version of that `SaveLogItem` method (`SaveLogItemAsync` maybe?), then you could await it and make everything `async`:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> CreateRequest([FromBody] DnsRecordDto RecordRequested)
{
    var result = await IsRecordRequestedNull()
}

public async Task<bool> IsRecordRequestedNull(DnsRecordDto RecordRequested)
{
    bool flag = false;
    if (RecordRequested == null)
    {
        flag = true;
        await _commonRepository.SaveLogItemAsync(Constants.TransactionFailedBadData, Constants.STARTING, transId, LogLevel.Trace);
    }
    return flag;
}
```

But I don't know where that `SaveLogItem` method is coming from, so I can't say if there is an async version available to you.

If it's a method you wrote yourself, and you want it to run asynchronously, then that's where you need to start. Look at where it is doing any I/O operations (reading/writing files, making network requests, etc.) and change it to use `async` versions of those calls (usually with the suffix "Async") and await them. Then you can change that method, and any methods that call it, to `async`.

Microsoft has a series of very well written articles about asynchronous programming that you might benefit from reading: [Asynchronous programming with async and await](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/index)

Comment: Ok. I follow. Let us keep aside the fact whether i decorate Task<ActionResult> CreateRequest with an async keyword or not. It is an action method in a controller. does it run asynchronously or synchronous?

Comment: It will only run asynchronously if you use `async` and `await`. But don't confuse asynchronous with parallel. If two requests come in at the same time, they will both be served at the same time on different threads. That is parallel. But without `async`/`await`, each of those two requests will run synchronously, meaning that if they wait for any I/O operation, the thread will be locked idle, doing nothing. If it ran asynchronously, that thread could be used for something else (another request) while it waits. This is important in ASP.NET because it has a limited number of threads.

Answer (score 1):

Your method is decorated with an *async* keyword, which implies that you want to run your code asynchronously , but the *async* keyword by itself doesn't do anything, you have to have an *await* somewhere in the body of your method. so just like @Gabriel Luci suggested, check if there's an asynchronous version of `SaveLogItem`, so you can *await*. if not, just remove the *async* and you should be fine.